# Count specific elements of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to count specific elements ('host_name') of an array.

My function is decoding a json file and returning the array.

file.json

```
{
    "href": "https://webservice:8080",
    "items": [
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server1"
            },
            "href": "https://server1:8080"
        },
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server2"
            },
            "href": "https://server2:8080"
        },
        {
            "Hosts": {
                "cluster_name": "cluster1",
                "host_name": "server3"
            },
            "href": "https://server3:8080"
        }
    ]
}
```

My php page to decode the json file :

functions.php

```
function test($clusterName)
{
$content = file_get_contents($clusterName.".json");
                $content = utf8_encode($content);
                $result = json_decode($content, true);

                return  $result;
}
```

And my page where i'd like to display the number of host names :

page.php

```
$result = test("mycluster");
echo "<p>".count($result['Hosts']['host_name'])."</p>";
```

But I have an undefined index for 'Hosts' when I do this. I tried some things, I can tell that the array is well there (print_r shows it), but I really can't count elements of it.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the problem to count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count the elemets of "items".

```
echo "<p>".count($result['items'])."</p>";
```

Comment: Same answer : Undefined index: items

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$c = count($result['items']) ;
```

Comment: Can we see a print_r of $result as returned by test()?

Comment: Ok my bad, it works now. I changed the code in the meantime and I was returning $result['items'] in my function instead of $result. So it's good now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the items and hosts and check if host_name is present.

```
$result = test("mycluster");

$count = 0;
foreach($result['items'] as $item) {
    $count += isset($item['Hosts']) && isset($item['Hosts']['host_name']) ? 1 : 0;
}
print_r($count); // will print 3
```